# prove that the multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb C$ of $i:=0+i1$ is equal to its additive inverse in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

i need to be able to prove that the multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb C$ of $i:=0+i1$ is equal to its additive inverse in $\mathbb C$, hence we are able to write $\frac{1}{i}=-i$

is the question asking if the  multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb C$ of $i:=0+i1$ is equal to the additive inverse of $i:=0+i1$ or the additive inverse in $\mathbb C$? Because obviously multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb C$ is not equal to the additive inverse in $\mathbb C$.

to solve this, assuming i am correct in my interpretation of the question, i have found the additive id of $i:=0+i1$ to be  $0+i0$,

but this gives the inverse of  $i:=0+i1$ as $0+i(-1)$  which is not equal to  $i:=0+i1$

Could someone please help me prove this or tell me if i have misunderstood the question.

Many thanks

Comment: The title is just not right. The multiplicative inverse of $i$ is $-i$ because $i(-i)=-i^2=-(-1)=1$.

Comment: Yes, a lot of misunderstanding. They seem to be asking you to prove, for the sole number $i$, that its multiplicative inverse it equal to its additive inverse. But only for the number $i$ (actually also for $-i$ it is true, but they are not asking it). As you point out, $-i$ is the additive inverse of $i$. So, you need to prove that $i\cdot(-i)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking to show that the additive inverse of $i$ in $\mathbb C$ and the multiplicative inverse of $i$ in $\mathbb C$ coincide. That is, to show that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$. The fact that for general $z\in \mathbb C$ it is not the case that $\frac{1}{z}=-z$, does not mean that such an equality never holds.

To show that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ you can proceed in several ways. For instance, if you know the general formula for $\frac{1}{z}$ for nonzero $z\in \mathbb C$, then you can apply it for $z=i$ and see that you will indeed obtain $-i$.

Another way is to recall the meaning of the multiplicative inverse: $\frac{1}{z}=w$ precisely when $w\cdot z=1$. So, to show that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ it suffices to show that $(-i)\cdot i=1$. Can you establish that?

Comment: makes much more sense!